# Try-except for unknown function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, try-except

I'm trying to make a function that will test if a function exists or not, and then return a boolean value based on if it exists or not.

Here's my code; however, Python IDLE 3.5 tells me that there is an error with my eval() statement, but I don't see what's wrong:

```
def testFunction(entity):
    try eval(entity)():
        return True
    except NameError:
        return False
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `try` statement is wrong. It should have been -

```
def testFunction(entity):
    try: return callable(eval(entity))
    except NameError:
        return False
```

You don't need to call the function either (to check whether its available or not). The above uses the built-in function [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) , to check whether the `entity` is a function/class or so.

---

But If you are checking for simple functions (and not builtin functions or module functions like `module.function`) I would say it would be better to use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary and search in it, rather than using `eval()` . Example -

```
def testFunction(entity):
    try: return callable(globals()[entity])
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

Please note, the above would not return `True` for builtin functions , or functions that you access like - `module.function`, etc. If you would need to test for those as well, and if you trust the source from where you get `entity` , you can fallback to using `eval` .

Comment: Oh, ok. But why is it better to use globals() instead of eval()? Don't they accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Because [`eval` is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)